# Simple redirect complicated by rules below it

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want a simple redirect in my .htaccess, with the goal of making a "shortlink" to a long URL.

mydomain.com/short

to take the user to

http://www.mydomain.com/blahblah/foo/bar/foobar/uglylongurl.html

So I tried this:

```
Redirect /short http://www.mydomain.com/blahblah/foo/bar/foobar/uglylongurl.html
```

but within the same .htaccess file is:

```
  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is causing my simple redirect to have "short" appended as a query string.

I have tried [R] to redirect immediately and I've also tried [L] to stop processing if the first (simplest) rule is used. Both give me a 500 error.

I hope someone knows what I'm missing here. I am on a tight deadline and this is just killing me :P Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Many thanks to the responder who got this working. I had the redirect above the other rules, however, I needed to change it to a RewriteRule and add the additional code as in his example.

One more issue arose after this....and with his suggestion, I am adding the next layer of the problem to this question (instead of to the comment reply, where the code tags didn't work and it was hard to read).

---

So here is my next issue. The first one in the list works just fine, whether redirecting to an internal page or an external URL. But subsequent rules give me a 404 error. Here is what it looks like (and note they are all *before* the one that appends the query string):

```
RewriteRule ^short/?$ /ugly/long/url.html [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/sweet/?$ /another/ugly/long/url.html [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/offsite/?$ http://www.somewhereelse.com/with/a/long/url.html [L,NC]


  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of rewrite rules in pretty important. First have your desired rule then rest of the rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^short/?$ /blahblah/foo/bar/foobar/uglylongurl.html [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You rock! Almost solved.
I have several of these to redirect, and this only works for the first one; following items throw a 404 error.
'RewriteRule ^short/?$ /blahblah/foo/bar/foobar/uglylongurl.html [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^better/?$ /blahblah/foo/bar/foobar/uglylongurl-number2.html [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^nice/?$ http://somewherelse.com/foo/bar/foobar/uglylongurl-onotherdomain.html [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]'

Comment: If you have multiple `short` URIs then you need to have as many rules like the one I showed above **before** last rule which grabs everything.

Comment: Also please post the code by editing question (difficult to read from comments)

Comment: Thank you, I have done so. Tried to use 'code' in the comments, didn't work so well. :P

Comment: Ah you have leading slash in rule that doesn't work so use `^sweet/?$` instead of `^/sweet/?$` see my example above.

Comment: I was looking for something complicated, and I missed something obvious. Thank you. One last issue - one of the URLs I am redirecting to has a # in it. How can I escape that one character so it does not turn into %23 and throw a 404?

Comment: Oh that is also easy just add `NE` flag in it, like this: `RewriteRule ^short/?$ /ugly/long/url.html#tag [L,NC,NE]`

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. We're good to go, and I've learned much.